# Why am I getting a list index out of range error when using Google Vision?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-vision

This is a two-part question. The first is figuring out the out of range error.

Im using code straight from the Google API source.

```
import argparse
import io
import os
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd
from pillow_utility import draw_borders, Image
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="<path to json token>"

def get_crop_hint(path):
#Detect crop hints on a single image and return the first result.
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

crop_hints_params = vision.types.CropHintsParams(aspect_ratios=[1])
image_context = vision.types.ImageContext(crop_hints_params=crop_hints_params)

response = client.crop_hints(image=image, image_context=image_context)
hints = response.crop_hints_annotation.crop_hints

# Get bounds for the first crop hint using an aspect ratio of 1:1
vertices = hints[0].bounding_poly.vertices

return vertices
```

When I run this against a Tif image I get the following error:

```
File "googlecrop.py", line 31, in get_crop_hint
vertices = hints[0].bounding_poly.vertices
IndexError: list index (0) out of range
```

However, if I run it against the same image saved out as a Jpeg, it works as expected. It's not a file size error as I first thought because that is an entirely different error message.

---

My end goal is to be able to detect the crop hints, and by using a bounding box of my choice, crop to that box. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Apparently with the Tif image `hints` is empty.